# VB.NET check XML Node with ID exists

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I need to read a specific node from my xml but I'm getting an error (as attached) when the result doesn't exist, I'm using asp vb.net. How do I run a check to see whether the rep node with the specified id exists? Please see code below. Any help with this problem would be great

[image]

**XML**

```
<repbio>
  <rep id="1021">
    <name>Tom Adams</name>
    <area>England</area>
    <invested>2004</invested>
    <since>2012</since>
  </rep>
</repbio>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Files/RepBio.xml"))

Dim n As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/repbio/rep[@ID='" & RepID & "']")

Response.Write(n("area").InnerText)
RepAreaXml.Text = n("area").InnerText
```

Comment: Are you forced to use XPath or can you used LINQ?

Comment: I'm not able to use LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) about `XmlNode.SelectSingleNode()` (emphasize mine) :

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Xml.XmlNode
>
> The first XmlNode that matches the XPath query or **Nothing if no matching node is found**.

So you should be able to check if the return value is not `Nothing` :

```
Dim n As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/repbio/rep[@ID='" & RepID & "']/area")

If n IsNot Nothing Then
    Response.Write(n("area").InnerText)
    RepAreaXml.Text = n("area").InnerText
End If
```

Side note : Element and attribute name are case-sensitive. You should use `@id` in xpath if it is `id="1021"` in the XML.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was looking for, changed ID to id and added the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Files/RepBio.xml"))

Dim n As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/repbio/rep[@ID='" & RepID & "']")
try
   Response.Write(n("area").InnerText)
   RepAreaXml.Text = n("area").InnerText
Catch ex As Exception
   Response.Write("Not Found")
   RepAreaXml.Text = String.Empty
End Try
```